# Activity entra em onPause somente na primeira vez que é chamada

Tags: java, android, mobile

Tenho uma activity de PedidoCad que chama um ProdutoCons, segue codigo para abrir 
ProdutoCons:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(PedidoCadActivity.this, ProdutoConsActivity.class);
 intent.putExtra("activity", "pedidoCad");
 startActivityForResult(intent, 2);
```

Quando escolho o item que desejo na activity ProdutoCons, clico no botão que executa esse código:

```
setTotalItem();
setObjPedidoItens();
setDescPorcentagem();
setDescValor();
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putParcelable("objPedidoItem", objPedidoItem);
Intent i = new Intent();
i.putExtras(bundle);
setResult(1, i);
finish();
```

O problema é que ao finalizar ProdutoCons pela segunda vez para adicionar o segundo produto, ele não cai no onResume, ele vai para o onCreate, e o ListView que é adicionado os itens é reiniciado toda vez não sei por que motivo.

Comment: alguem pode me dar esse help?

Comment: Isto acontece na sua activity PedidoCad ?

Comment: Sim, quando volta pro OnActivityResult zera tudo da activity PedidoCad

Comment: Tente colocar o mesmo contexto que você usou em intent: PedidoCadactivity.this.startActivityForResult